# Prove x . y' . z' is y' . z'

Tags: boolean-algebra

Please, how can I prove that x . y' . z' simplifies to y' . z'?

I have tried without success. Below is the context of my question; I am taking a course on Coursera

[image: Context]

Comment: You can't prove it since it's not true.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus please then how did they arrive at the second equation/expression?

Comment: You can use a truth table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, $x\cdot y'\cdot z'≠ y'\cdot z'$ as it depends on the truth value of $x.$

However, in your specific case, the expression is $(\lnot x\land \lnot z)\lor (x\land \lnot y\land\lnot z).$

Note that if $x$ is false, then the $\lnot x$ literal in the left clause (i.e. $\lnot x\land \lnot z$) will become true, and if it's false then the one in the right clause will be true. So only in this case, it's safe to just "remove" it in the right clause as its truth value specifically in the right clause will not affect the overall outcome. This is because there is a $\lnot z$ in both the clauses. More generally, this is a simple law in Boolean algebra:
$$a\cdot b +a\cdot b' = a\cdot (b+b') = a$$

So in this case, it's a slightly more complicated version of $(\lnot x\land \lnot z)\lor (x\land\lnot z)$ which is just $\lnot z.$ Hence it is independent of the value of $x.$

Note, for better understanding, that the 2 clauses are separated with a logical OR ($\lor$) operation, so for the whole expression to be true, either or both of the clauses need to be true.

P.S. - My apologies for the inconsistency in notation.
Hope it's okay :)

Comment: Thanks so much. Your answer helped so much.